# GhostScript save the original file too

Tags: pdf, printing, ghostscript

I created a virtual printer with the "Multi File Port Monitor" software and this virtual printer call the following Ghostscript:

```
"C:\GS\[version]\bin\gswin64c.exe"  -r204 -dMinFeatureSize=1  -dInterpolateControl=-1 -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -dAlignToPixels=1  -dNOINTERPOLATE -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=png16m   -dDownScaleFactor=1  -sOutputFile="%f" -
```

The script creates an output file and it's ok, but I need to save the original file too.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Humm, I understand. so it's not so easy... 
I have an application where a person will download a PDF file a send it to a thermal printer.
The PDF is converted to a PNG image with 204 dpi and saved as a file. But I lose a lot of quality and the code bar doesn't work so well. So I would read the PDF before to get the codebar string and send it as ESC/POS command.

Comment: The problem's that the application is a third party. 
So I don't have access to the file before the user clicks on "print".